# Changing content of class using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, tags

I started reading JavaScript in W3schools and testing out/changing few things in the examples they give so I can see what is doing what but didn't manage to identify the syntax, yet.

Below is the original code to change p tag content,  *the [link](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_intro_inner_html) to it.*

```
<p id="demo">
    JavaScript can change the content of an HTML element.
</p>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
    x = document.getElementById("demo");  // Find the element
    x.innerHTML = "Hello JavaScript!";    // Change the content
}
</script>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click Me!</button>
```

I want to know how to change contents with the same class, but failed as you can see that the example below doesn't work. [Fiddle of code below](http://jsfiddle.net/37jq9/).

```
<p class="demo">
    JavaScript can change the content of an HTML element.
</p>

<p class="demo">Yolo</p>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
    x = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");  // Find the element
    x.innerHTML = "Hello JavaScript!";    // Change the content
}
</script>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click Me!</button>
```

If you could show me how ^^" and help me understand, is "getElementById" a variable that could be anything else or is it a command?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your x - is array of elements. try to use loop:

```
<body>

<p class="demo">JavaScript can change the content of an HTML element.</p>    
<p class="demo">Yolo</p>   

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click Me!</button>

<script>        
function myFunction()
{
x=document.getElementsByClassName("demo");  // Find the elements
    for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
    x[i].innerText="Hello JavaScript!";    // Change the content
    }

}

</script>
</body>
```

See [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/37jq9/7/)

Comment: In the fiddle you have an extra line "console.log(x)" D:: what is it?

Comment: See this link to find answer for this: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console-api

Comment: it just displays a message in the console.

Comment: I use it just to make sure that everything I do is right

Comment: Oh ok, I thought it was strage since it worked normally without it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Notice how when you use:

```
x=document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
```

It is Elements instead of Element.  This is because it returns <del>an array</del> a HTMLCollection of all the elements with one particular class name.  In order to combat this, you can choose the first element <del>in the array</del>:

```
x=document.getElementsByClassName("demo")[0];
```

Comment: I read your answer like 4 times then I understood the array thingy! (I had an idea of array from Pascal). Tested it and worked, [0] changed the first text, [1] changed the 2nd. Thanks! Tho the loop thingy was what I intended

Comment: var x=document.getElementsByClassName("demo")[0].innerHTML; but i want to access this using jquery then how can i get variable x

Comment: You will get variable x using jQuery like this x = $('.demo');

Answer (score 3):

It is easier to use jQuery with Javascript

See this example:
http://jsfiddle.net/37jq9/3/

If you use jquery instead of calling

```
x=document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
```

you can use

```
x = $('.demo');
```

but you can just call the function like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        $('.demo').text('Hello Javascript');
    })   
})
```

Comment: "I started reading JavaScript in W3schools" - Harlequin should learn javascript at first.

Comment: "*Easier to use jQuery with Java*"? — what? Java != JavaScript, and ideally JavaScript should be learned before developing a reliance any library.