# How to code JS function that changes text of all elements with a certain class?

Tags: javascript, html, function

Let's say I have multiple elements (for example a `title` and `p` tag) that all have the same `class="title"`. How would I make a JS function that changes the text of those elements to the word "example".

Comment: Use cycle `for {}` or method `foreach()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the style of elements with same class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20946355/how-to-change-the-style-of-elements-with-same-class-name)

Comment: or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21813122/changing-content-of-class-using-javascript/21813259

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query all the elements:

```
let elems = document.querySelectorAll(".title");
```

Loop and change the text

```
for (let i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) elems[i].textContent = "Example";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select all elements of a class by using `document.getElementsByClassName` which will return an array-like collection. You can then iterate over the collection using a `for` loop to change the text content of each element.

Answer (score 0):

You could first get all elements of a certain class like shown below
and then iterate trough the elements.

```js
let elements = document.getElementsByClassName('test');
for(let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  let element = elements[i];
  if(element.nodeName.trim().toLowerCase() === 'div') {
    //Do your stuff
  }
}
console.log(elements);
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test-2">
  <div class="test another-class">
    <div class="test-3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You don't have to use toLowerCase but, i prefer this way. Otherwise
all the tagNames will be in caps. Also the trim() is not required.
I like to include it, if something acts buggy, and inserts unexpected
white spaces you if condition might fail.

I would suggest that you use jquery for this:

```
$('p.title, title.title').text('Insert your text');
```